# Angular2 to form is invalid for auto selected dropdown

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

My html looks like below

```
<div>My app
  <form [formGroup]="selectForm">
    <select [formControl]="selectForm.controls['filename']">
    <option *ngFor="let item of files; let i = index;" [value]="item" [selected]="i==0">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!selectForm.valid">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

My component is as below

```
export class App {
    files: Array<any>=[];
    selectForm: FormGroup;
    name:string;
    constructor(private _formbulider: FormBuilder) {
        this.selectForm = this._formbulider.group({
        'filename': ['', Validators.required]
        });
        this.files = [1];
    }
}
```

But my problem is submit is disabled since form is invalid. I expect form to be valid. Plunkr link is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4OqxOKIbjh6Zs8bZj0F8?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize field with value, like this:

```
'filename': [this.files[0], Validators.required]
```

Then you can remove `[selected]` tag from HTML code.

```
* Edit
```

Another option is to use ngModel directive and that's the way I prefer the most.

Check the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Q4LEi58E4SIoDSs06tB?p=preview) with updated code.

Comment: It won't work your way because the value is attached after form initialization so the form cannot know about change. If you want to do it this way you should also use ngModel binding.

Comment: Is there any other method to accomplish this

Comment: You can use [ngModel] directive, do you want me to show you an example?

Comment: There you are, I just updated answer. Mark it as accepted if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your component as below :

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>My app
    <form [formGroup]="selectForm">

      <select formControlName="filename">
        <option *ngFor="let item of files; let i = index;" [value]="item" [selected]="i==0">{{item}}</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!selectForm.valid"> Submit </button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  files: Array<any>=[];
  selectForm: FormGroup;
  name:string;
  constructor(private _formbulider: FormBuilder) {
    this.files = [1,2,4,5,6];
    this.selectForm = _formbulider.group({
      filename: [this.files[0], Validators.required]
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: default selection does not happen in ur code plz check